# Configuring popup to automatically redirect to webpage using ArcGIS Pro / Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro

Is there a way to redirect the user to a specific webpage on clicking a certain polygon on a map?

[image: Instead of a popup, the user must be redirected to a website]

Instead of a popup, the user must be sent to a website.

If this is possible how can this be achieved?

Comment: I think you should investigate hyperlinks.